# Is it Haram to work in Banks?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, work

I was wondering would it be haram to work in a bank as the banks profits are a result of interest which is haram in Islam, if it is haram would that mean it would be haram even if a person acquired a job in a bank which does not relate to the financial departments, because the banks profit is haram and by a person working their it would mean that the non halal money is passed on to him as a salary?

Comment: Where will you work that doesn't work with interest? Banks work with interest. Engineers work with interest. Doctors and hospitals work with interest. Tradespeople work with interest. You'd have to have an isolated industry that has no connection to the modern economic principles for your job not to deal with interest. And I don't think such an industry exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to work in them myself but the truth is, whether you deal with interest directly or not, you are aiding and facilitating it- It is haram

> 'Abdullah bin Masud and Jabir bin Abdullah both reported Rasolullah cursed the accepter of interest and its payer, and one who records it, and the two witnesses, and he said: They are all equal.

Would it be ok to work as a get-away driver for bank robbers because your job in the operation, i.e driving, is halal itself? Clearly not

I know its easy to say and hard to live it, but trust in Allah and he will provide for you from places you couldn't even imagine InshAllah

Comment: there is no clarity in question and answer is not based on verses from Quran and hadith

Answer (score 4):

The only problem with present day banks are the interest/usury (riba) that is involved.

If you have no direct involvement in any riba transaction, then it's fine to work there.

> 'Abdullah bin Masud and Jabir bin Abdullah both reported Rasolullah
>   cursed the accepter of interest and its payer, and one who records it,
>   and the two witnesses, and he said:
>   **They are all equal.**

[(Sahih Muslim)](http://sunnah.com/muslim/22/132)

And by two witnesses it means the ones who are partaking in the contract.

So if you can avoid these situations, you're good to go.

Comment: "f you have no direct involvement in any riba transaction, then it's fine to work there." brother @Sayyid, if some one working in a bank it hard to refuse to your manager to handle only other type of transactions. Bank will kick out such employee who will not follow bank policy.

Answer (score 0):

there are Syari'a banks in my country but, i have once use service of that syari'a's bank and the system is still riba, i was disappointed that time , and refused to use a bank system, except only transfer,

the bank profit must use syari'as law of islam, but until now i havent see the real  syaria's bank yet. i dont know if it exists in your country. if it exists work there the system syaria is recommended in islam.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, You can work in a bank if there are no jobs available what so ever and if you are required to work (so maybe to get money for your family or something such).
However, while you are working there you have to be looking for another job.