# Is working for a bank as a software engineer Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, banking, software, profession

If I have to work as a software engineer in a banking company is it Haram?

I have this doubt because, that bank will be working solely on the basis of interest, which is haram.

I am an active part of the very beginning of the process.

Comment: If it is contributing towards intrest in one way or another it would be haram, as it is contributing towards the bigger picture, i had a bank job offer and i turned it down for that reason, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17293/is-it-haram-to-work-in-bank

Comment: as a rule, if you are absolutely certain that it is a Haram act, it would be Haram, although I recommend you to make more research if the act of Bank is Haram...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be related to the part in which you are working. Since as I found the viewpoint of Ayatollah Sistani, according to his ruling:

> In case working in the bank is in a part which is related to Rabawi
>   transactions and somewhat be effective in fulfilling of that, then it
>   is not permissible for him to work there. But working in the parts of
>   the bank (mentioned bank) and getting income in lieu of that doesn’t
>   matter (no problem) in case it is not related somehow to the
>   transactions which canonically are haram.
>
> Hence the bank clerks who are involved Riba, ought to change their
>   positions (at work) to the other parts which are not involved Riba in
>   order to escaping from Riba.

Ultimately you'd notice regarding the sort of your working. Actually if the position which you are working in, is related to Rabawi transactions, then you must change your position to a permissible part.

---

**Reference**:

- [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/7353/?ref=sbttl#gsc.tab=0)